# "Joel test" is translated to "Test de Joël" on French version of Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

On every job from Careers, the "Joel test" string is translated to "Test de Joël" (note the diaeresis sign (2 dots) over the *e*) in the French version. The diaeresis (also called trema) is used to indicate that the *e* must be pronounced.

It's surprising because I don't think it's common to translate names in French. For example *Peter Jackson* is not translated to *Pierre Jackson* (even if [*Peter* and *Pierre*](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-french/peter#tr) are translations). There is an exception with people whose names are now known in History, for example *Alexander the Great* is *Alexandre le Grand* in French (this example is not the best because his real name is in Greek but you get the idea).

So I think it should be changed to "Test de Joel" because it comes from "Joel Spolsky", not "Joël Spolsky".

See this [random example](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/61457/web-developer-int%C3%A9grateur-front-end-convertigo) and switch the language at the bottom of the page in order to view this.

### Update:

I just saw that it may be a choice from Joel himself, see his own website:

- English: [I’m your host, **Joel** Spolsky, ...](http://www.joelonsoftware.com)
- French: [**Joël** à propos de logiciel](http://french.joelonsoftware.com)

It's the same on Wikipedia:

- English: [Joel Spolsky](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky)
- French: [Joël Spolsky](http://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo%C3%ABl_Spolsky)

Comment: I now have http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7szoIOkZCDI stuck in my head, just with "Joël".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We'll get this fixed with our translators.  We have a "do not translate" list which includes things like company names etc...  Joel's name doesn't need to be translated...

Answer (score 12):

Well, when I studied French in high school I always wrote my name as "Joël Spolsky" so I think that's correct. That's also the way it's translated on french.joelonsoftware.com (See [Le test de Joël](http://french.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/TheJoelTest.html)).

Ideally the wording in our French glossary should match the wording that Serge Wautier and Moez Mahfoudh used in that original 2000 translation of The Joel Test.

Comment: Hi. It's a honor to have your feedback, thanks. Do you remember if it was your choice or the translater's choice to translate/localize your first name? As I said in my question, it's not a common practice to translate names. Anyway, if you prefer than your first name is written "Joël" in french, I can update this question in order to ask the developers to revert the changes.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that we love rules, and we love exceptions too. Looks a bit schizophrenic ...  My name is jean, which is a male first name here in France, and, as I know, a female one in US, so knowing that  the female version of jean in France is jeannette, how do you translate "jean et jeannette" which is a roman of french author  Théophile Gautier ?      I recovered your copies in 10 minutes !

Comment: @JeanDavy actually I think *Jeanne* is the female variant of *Jean* (see [Jeanne d'Arc](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanne_d%27Arc)). Is your comment addressed to Joel or me? Anyway, my comment was about asking directly Joel how he prefer to write his first name in French, I don't think rules or exceptions are helpful here since first names can be written the way the parents want (see [Le Tumblr de la Ligue des officiers d'état-civil](http://liguedesofficiersdetatcivil.tumblr.com/), where first names are written without following any rule).